# Transliteration words from database using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to replace words from a database, for this purpose I'm using this code.

```
input_content = Regex.Replace(input_content, "\\s+\r\n", "\r\n");//remove blank lines
    var Value = input_content.Split(' ');
    //try
    //{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnection"];
        string strcon = "select * from english_hindi_words where english=@englishwords";
    for (int i = 0; i < Value.Length; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcon, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@englishwords", Value[i].Trim());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "content"+ Value[i].Trim());
        try
        {
            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["content" + Value[i].Trim()].Rows[0];
            if (Value[i].Trim() == drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString())
            {
                hindicontent2 += "<span title='" + Value[i] + "'>" + drow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString() + " </span>";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            hindicontent2 += "<span title='" + Value[i] + "'>" + Value[i] + " </span>";
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = hindicontent2.ToString();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //}
```

The code is working good, but if I have 500+ words in my textbox, it will take 3+ minutes. I'm new to C# and I want to know if there is any other fast way to do this.

Comment: How many words are in the database? Is the query optimised? Why are you using datasets and data adapters?

Comment: @stuartd I have 100k words in the database. Is any fastest way to retrieve data and replace words?

Comment: There are many ways. For example. 1. Load 100K words into memory cache and don't use db... There could be more sophisticated ways.For example, 2. enumerate all words and take 2 first letters. Then build your SQL with where clause  `word like 'ab%' or word like 'cd%'`. This way you will load subset of potentially matching words. And you finish matching them in code. If the word is 1 letter or exactly 2 letters - match exact word. Make good use of index. `LIKE` work with indexes.

Comment: Small question, is your column for the english words indexed? I agree with T.S.'s answer but if your column with the english words is indexed, it can speed things up.

Comment: @T.S. Thanks, Example 2 is working good.